# Newer kernel for Edison available?

Tags: intel-edison

The Edison could be perfect for me if a newer kernel version would be available (i still use 3.10.17-poky-edison+, which is pretty old now).

I'm running a 32bit Archlinux and all updates (without kernel) worked fine until today. Now i get serious problems with systemd-231 (logind and networkd services).

Anybody knows about newer kernel versions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The Edison in more or less usable shape will be in v4.8. In v4.9 is expecting to have WiFi and SD slot working. All of upstream related development is going on (not active, though) in the https://github.com/andy-shev/linux/tree/eds tree. Check it from time to time for updates. The discussion about current state is happening on https://communities.intel.com/thread/75472. Also third party Wiki is available: https://edison.internet-share.com.