# Intel Edison no longer supported?

Tags: android-things, intel-edison

Last year I got pretty excited with Android things and bought an Intel Edison to try it on. I recently found some time to work on it and realized it is no longer a supported hardware and I am not able to do any thing with it. :(

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a) your hardware no longer being supported is not a programming issue, b) there is nothing we can do about your hardware no longer being supported, and c) *Any help would be appreciated!* is not a meaningful question.

Comment: _"and realized it is no longer a supported hardware"_ If you found this out, why did you ask?

Comment: You can still experiment with version `0.4.0-devpreview` which I believe is where the support stopped. Then once you are comfortable go buy an NXP or RPi :-)

Comment: @KenWhite, to the 2): we might do nothing, though the community still supports it.

Comment: This question has been already asked.

Comment: @Blundell Can you please provide a link to where I could find the downloads for the 0.4.0-devpreview?

Comment: @0andriy Would be helpful if you provide a link to the question that was already asked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799334/newer-kernel-for-edison-available/39259143#39259143 It is not exact answer to your question, it is rather way to make Edison somehow useful.

Answer (score 2):

Intel has stopped support, but there is still community activity: there is a Yocto image builder that currently builds Yocto Warrior and Debian Buster with kernel v5.4 here: https://edison-fw.github.io/meta-intel-edison/